# ExtJS 4.2.1 changing Header Height of Panels,.. with SASS

Tags: extjs, themes, sass, extjs4.2

i am currently styling my extjs application and want to change the header size of my title bars in my Application..

i am using the neptune theme as a base... i found out that their height is 36 px.. still when i just overwrite the class of the panel header or something like that the content is not positioned correct because there is also a absolute positioning with top 36px..

so before i do start hacking around here.. i am questioning myself if there is a proper way to do this? I tried to search for a specific sass variable or something though i didnt find anything..

Please help me out!
If you need more information dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the header is 36px because of the padding, which is set with the SASS variable `$panel-header-padding`, which defaults to `9px 9px 10px` in Neptune (defined in `sass/var/panel/Panel.scss`).  If you set this variable to something else, you should be able to control the height of your panel header.

Comment: i am aware of the $panel-header-padding variable. though i also want to increase the fontsize in the header. So if a am increasing the padding i assume i am not increasing the size of the content placeholder?!?? do i ?

Comment: You can change the font size by changing the `$panel-header-font-size` variable, which defaults to `$font-size`, which defaults to `13px`.  You cannot directly change the container size, but using these 2 variables should be able to give you the sizing you are looking for.

Comment: i've already tried this... but this is not what i am looking for cuz its cropping my font... !http://i.imgur.com/ZHdxtSy.png!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Then you will also want to change `$panel-header-line-height` to be something bigger than your font size.  HTH.

Comment: Is there somewhere a doku where i can find all these variables?

Comment: They are available under the "CSS Variables" section of the docs:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel
Although I sometimes find it easier to look at the files themselves, under `ext\packages\[theme]\sass\var\Panel.scss`